# Finding all palindromic word pairs

Tags: haskell

I came up with an unreal problem: finding all palindromic word pairs in a vocabulary, so I wrote the solution below,

```hs
import Data.List

findParis :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]

findPairs ss =
  filter ((== 2) . length) 
    . groupBy ((==) . reverse) 
    . sortBy (compare . reverse) 
    $ ss

main = do
  print . findPairs . permutations $ ['a'..'c'] 

-- malfunctioning: only got partial results [["abc","cba"]]
-- expected: [["abc","cba"],["bac","cab"],["bca","acb"]]
```

Could you help correct it if worthy of trying?

**@Solution**

Having benefited from `@David Young @chi` comments the tuned working code goes below,

```hs
import Data.List (delete)
import Data.Set hiding (delete, map)

findPairs :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [([a], [a])]

findPairs ss =
  let
    f [] = []
    f (x : xs) =
      let y = reverse x
      in
        if x /= y
        then
          let ss' = delete y xs
          in (x, y) : f ss'
        else f xs
  in
    f . toList
      . intersection (fromList ss)
      $ fromList (map reverse ss)
```

Comment: The problem is that `sortBy (compare . reverse)` doesn't always put equivalent strings next to each other. The result of `sortBy (compare . reverse)  $ permutations ['a'..'c']` is `["acb","bac","abc","cba","bca","cab"]`. I *think* this means that the transitive property of a partial order is violated.

Comment: `sortBy x` requires `x` to be an ordering relation (a total order, according to the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy)). `compare . reverse` is not even transitive.

Comment: What about using `intersect ss (map reverse ss)`? I'd optimize this writing my own variant of `intersect` exploiting `Ord` (or passing through `Data.Set` is I felt lazy). The library `intersect` is only O(n^2), so we can improve on that.

Comment: @sof As chi wrote, you should use another data structure than a list, for better efficiency.

Comment: Is "race" and "car" a palindromic word pair?

Comment: No, not in this case. But it's just a hypothetical problem of mine as said at the beginning.

Comment: @sof The "tuned working code" should go in an answer, not in the question. Also, you're reversing words more than needed; you could do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

-- find classes of equivalence by comparing canonical forms (CF)
findEquivalentSets :: Ord b => (a->b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
findEquivalentSets toCanonical =

      filter ((>=2) . length)                            -- has more than one
                                                         -- with the same CF?

    . groupBy ((((== EQ) .) .) (comparing toCanonical))  -- group by CF

    . sortBy (comparing toCanonical)                     -- compare CFs

findPalindromes :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
findPalindromes = findEquivalentSets (\x -> min x (reverse x))
```

This function lets us find many kinds of equivalence as long as we can assign some effectively computable canonical form (CF) to our elements.

When looking for palindromic pairs, two strings are equivalent if one is a reverse of the other. The CF is the lexicographically smaller string.

```
findAnagrams :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
findAnagrams = findEquivalentSets sort
```

In this example, two strings are equivalent if one is an anagram of the other. The CF is the sorted string (banana → aaabnn).

Likewise we can find SOUNDEX equivalents and whatnot.

This is not terribly efficient as one needs to compute the CF on each comparison. We can cache it, at the expense of readability.

```
findEquivalentSets :: Ord b => (a->b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
findEquivalentSets toCanonical =

          map (map fst)                               -- strip CF

        . filter ((>=2) . length)                     -- has more than one
                                                      -- with the same CF?

        . groupBy ((((== EQ) .) .) (comparing snd))   -- group by CF

        . sortBy (comparing snd)                      -- compare CFs

        . map (\x -> (x, toCanonical x))              -- pair the element with its CF
```

Comment: Thanks, your using built-in constructs seems order of magnitude more performant than my own handcraft.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach you might want to consider.

Using `sort` implies that there's some keying function `word2key` that yields the same value for both words of a palindromic pair. The first one that comes to mind for me is

```
word2key w = min w (reverse w)
```

So, map the keying function over the list of words, sort, group by equality, take groups of length 2, and then recover the two words from the key (using the fact that the key is either equal to the word or its reverse.

Writing that, with a couple of local definitions for clarity, gives:

```
findPals :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
findPals = map (key2words . head) .
           filter ((== 2) . length) .
           groupBy (==) .
           sort .
           (map word2key)
  where word2key w = min w (reverse w)
        key2words k = [k, reverse k]
```

**Edit:**

I posted my answer in a stale window without refreshing, so missed the very nice response from n.m. above.

*Mea culpa*.

So I'll atone by mentioning that both answers are variations on the well-known (in Perl circles) "[Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)" which itself applies a common Mathematical pattern -- `h = f' . g . f` -- translate a task to an alternate representation in which the task is easier, do the work, then translate back to the original representation.

The Schwartzian transform tuples up a value with its corresponding key, sorts by the key, then pulls the original value back out of the key/value tuple.

The little hack I included above was based on the fact that `key2words` is the non-deterministic inverse relation of `word2key`. It is only valid when two words have the same key, but that's exactly the case in the question, and is insured by the `filter`.

```
overAndBack :: (Ord b, Eq c) => (a -> b) -> ([b] -> [c]) -> (c -> d) -> [a] -> [d]
overAndBack f g f' = map f' . g . sort . map f

findPalPairs :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
findPalPairs = overAndBack over just2 back
  where over w = min w (reverse w)
        just2  = filter ((== 2) . length) . groupBy (==)
        back   = (\k -> [k, reverse k]) . head
```

Which demos as

```
*Main> findPalPairs $ words "I saw no cat was on a chair"
[["no","on"],["saw","was"]]
```

Thanks for the nice question.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening pivot idea in clear text.